# Storing Firestore exports as versioned files vs using a timestamped location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am currently exporting my Firestore data to a timestamped subdirectory in a bucket using the code below. It runs in a scheduled (firebase) cloud function.

```
import { client } from "../firebase-admin-client";
import { getExportCollectionList } from "./helpers";

export async function createFirestoreExport() {
  const bucket = `gs://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}_backups/firestore`;
  const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();

  try {
    const databaseName = client.databasePath(
      process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      "(default)"
    );

    const collectionsToBackup = await getExportCollectionList();

    const responses = await client.exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: `${bucket}/${timestamp}`,
      collectionIds: collectionsToBackup
    });

    const response = responses[0];
    console.log(`Successfully scheduled export operation: ${response.name}`);
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw new Error(`Export operation failed: ${err.message}`);
  }
}
```

This has the advantage that you will get a list of exports each under its own timestamp. For example my script which imports the data to BigQuery will figure out the latest timestamp and load the data from there.

This approach has some drawbacks I think. There is no way to list directories in cloud storage. In order to figure out the latest timestamp I have to fetch a list of all objects (meaning all files of all exports) and then `split` and `reduce` these paths to extract a list of unique timestamps.

When keeping exports of months of data I can imagine this operation becomes quite inefficient.

So I'm thinking of storing the backups as versioned files, but I have no experience with this. If I understand correctly, with versioned files I can export the data each time to the same location, and (configurable) x versions of the files will persist in the bucket. You then have the ability to read any of available the versions if needed.

The bigquery import script could then load the data from the same location each time, automatically getting the latest export data.

So in my mind this would simplify things. Are there any drawbacks to using versioned files for backup data? Is this a recommended approach?

Comment: *"There is no way to list directories in cloud storage"* - that's not entirely true, it has a list API that you can use to discover paths to files under a prefix: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects

Comment: If I list the objects under my prefix `firestore/` where all my backups are located in timestamped directories, I get a list of all objects in every exported backup, so basically all files that live under that prefix on all levels. After making backups daily for months that list is going to be huge. I don't see how this qualifies as a "give me a list of directories in `firestore/'"

Comment: The size of the list isn't necessarily relevant - you can transform it down to what's useful for your purposes.  Or if you don't want to do that, then you certainly don't have to, but it is an option.

Comment: That's what I meant when I wrote "fetch a list of all objects (meaning all files of all exports) and then split and reduce these paths to extract a list of unique timestamps." It didn't seem very efficient or scalable to me.